# "Cannot GET /" with Connect on Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, node.js-connect

I'm trying to start serving some static web pages using `connect` like this:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var nowjs = require("now");
var io = require("socket.io");


var app = connect.createServer(
  connect.static(__dirname + '/public')
);

app.listen(8180);
```

So I added a simple `index.html` at the `/public` directory on the same directory as the `app.js` file is, but when I try to view the page on my browser I get this response from node:

> Cannot GET /

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code should work:

```js
var connect = require("connect");

var app = connect.createServer().use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8180);
```

Also in connect 2.0 .createServer() method deprecated. Use connect() instead.

```js
var connect = require("connect");

var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8180);
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks very much. All these old node.js articles makes me really confused with the deprecated things.

Comment: I have tried both of these and they both say that undefined is not a function. In the first example this tells me that .createServer() is not a function and in the second example __dirname is invalid.

Answer (score 38):

You'll see the message `Cannot GET /` if you don't specify which page it is that you're trying to get, in other words if your URL is something like `http://localhost:8180`. Make sure you enter a page name, e.g. `http://localhost:8180/index.html`.

Comment: yep... It just happened to me.

Comment: Also same behaviour if you have the wrong path, for example to a static file

Comment: I think this solution is what will mostly work for those using express.js

Comment: Simple but very useful answer. It fixed my simple "Cannot GET /" issue

Answer (score 26):

You may be here because you're reading the `Apress PRO AngularJS` book...

As is described in a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978734/node-connect-issue-object-function-createserver-has-no-method-static) by `KnarfaLingus`:

[START QUOTE]

The connect module has been reorganized. do:

```
npm install connect
```

**and also**

```
npm install serve-static
```

Afterward your `server.js` can be written as:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static'); 
var app = connect(); 

app.use(serveStatic('../angularjs')); 

app.listen(5000);
```

[END QUOTE]

Although I do it, as the book suggests, in a more concise way like this:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

connect().use(
    serveStatic("../angularjs")
).listen(5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for that also, helped me solve mine.  Incidentally I'm going through the ProAngularJS book trying to get it set up on my MacBookPro and I ended up structuring my directory as "Apress/angularjs", where server.js resides in the "Apress" directory; in that case the path in the server.js code would be serveStatic("angularjs").  Once I did that the simple test in Chapter 1 of the Apress book succeeded and I'm now successfully serving up the test page.  Thanks again @Serj for your post.

Answer (score 3):

You might be needed to `restart` the process if `app.get` `not` working. Press `ctl+c` and then `restart node app`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.   It was resolved as described above.

In my index.js

```
var port = 1338,
express = require('express'),
app = express().use(express.static(__dirname + '/')),
http = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Node server listening on port " + port);
});
```

and in my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My page
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src = "lib/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src = "lib/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the three.js was just in there for path testing.  This will set all child files to start at the root directory of your app.     Also  socket.io.js can be called automatically using `<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js">` through some dark magic (since there is physically a node_modules and lib directory in between) .

Answer (score 2):

The solution to "Cannot Get /" can usually be determined if you do an "ng build" in the command line.  You will find most often that one of your "imports" does not have the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = connect(); 
app.use(serveStatic('../angularjs'),  {default: 'angular.min.js'}); app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Create an angularjs directory. Make index.html file inside it.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: I am using serveStatic module, which does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try ***st***, a node module for serving static files. Setup is trivial.

```
npm install connect

npm install st
```

And here's how my server-dev.js file looks like:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var st = require('st');

var app = connect()
    .use(st('app/dev'));

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

or (with cache disabled):

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var st = require('st');

var app = connect();

var mount = st({
  path: 'app/dev',
  cache: false
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (mount(req, res)) return;
}).listen(8000);

app.use(mount);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to serve static files is to use "harp". It can be found here. You can serve up your files from the location you want via node is:

```
var harp = require("harp")
harp.server(projectPath [,args] [,callback])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. open cmd and go to the path of your project.(make sure that you are in "clientApp")
2. then build your project with "ng build" command. if there is an error the console will give you the error.
   [build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeEbD.png)

now you know what your error is.

Answer (score 0):

The Straight Forward Answer, include the code in your Node/Server index.js file

```
const path = require("path"); // include this in the file

router.get("/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public", "index.html"));
});
```

And if your are using `navigate()` in your `reactApp` use the above code at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

That was a silly mistake , I commented out the line that app.js uses for referencing routes.

This fix was to remove using express() directly.

[image]

And inside app.js you can define your customize routes

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You typically want to render templates like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

However you can also deliver static content - to do so use:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now everything in the /public directory of your project will be delivered as static content at the root of your site e.g. if you place default.htm in the public folder if will be available by visiting /default.htm

Take a look through the [express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html) and Connect Static middleware docs for more info.