# How to link files in NodeJS (+ let the user download the file when clicking it)?

Tags: node.js, express

I guess it is just a simple question but I can't solve it on my own.

(I'm using Express + NodeJS)

What I would like to have is a directory listing with the files contained in it. The files shall be linked so that a user could download them by just clicking the link (like the standard directory listing you get if you have e.g. a apache server without any index file).

To list the directory content I use

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('./anydir', function(err, files){
    files.forEach(function(file){
        res.send(file);
    });
});
```

(Notice: I did not include any error handling in this example as you can see)

Now I tried to just link the file by modifying the

```
res.send(file)
```

to

```
res.send('<a href=\"' + file + '\">' + file + '<br>');
```

but this just prints out the error message:

```
Cannot GET /anydir/File
```

... because I did not handle every file request in app.js.

How can I achieve my goal mentioned above?

Comment: Got it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-file-from-nodejs-server

Answer (score 1):

Just use `express.directory` and `express.static` as middleware, possibly with a user-defined middleware to set `Content-Disposition` headers.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('/var/', function(err, files){
    files.forEach(function(file){
        res.write('<a href=\"' + file + '\">' + file + '<br>');
    });
});
```

You put the content with write() not send().
Try this and let me know. I can see the list of files displayed correctly.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes it works but it only display the linked file but if you click on this link only the mentioned error is displayed

Comment: you can not open files outside /public/ folder if you do not have permission to that particular folder. If what you want is a static server for files check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627441/cannot-get-with-connect-on-node-js, also note that the href link has only the name of the file not the full path maybe thats the problem try: res.write('<a href=\"/var/' + file + '\">' + file + '<br>'); for example