# How connect npm connect module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I used command :`node-dev script.js`

```
{
    var connect = require('connect');
    var app = connect()
      .use(connect.static('public'))
      .use(function (req, res) {
        res.end("Couldn't find it.");
      })
      .listen(3000);
}
```

[image: here is error screen shot]

Comment: this code works fine for me once I copy paste it into a .js file and have run npm install connect

Comment: Sounds for me like a version conflict of npm . Your code will probably work with an older version of connect.
This post sums it up very well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static