# Installing node.js for angular - connect.static and karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, karma-runner

I'm trying to install a simple node webserver following the example in Pro AngularJS from apress.

I've installed node.js and the connect and karma modules.

I do get a warning when I installed karma via: "npm install -g karma" that says "optional dep failed, continuing" but then seems to install correctly.

I created a server.js based on the example:

```
var connect = require('connect');

connect.createServer(
    connect.static("../angularjs")
).listen(5000);
```

when I run it I get TypeError:Undefined is not a function pointing to connect.static.

Comment: have you done ``npm install connect``?

Comment: yes that works and it appears in the node_modules dir but karma isn't in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently in the latest build of connect the static middleware has been moved to it's own package.

[nodejs connect cannot find static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static)