# nodejs server is not displaying test.html

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to test my nodejs is install and configured correctly.  I am running on a MAC.

I have followed the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static) involving the server.

Below is the server I have setup.  The file resides in the ~/ directory.

```
  1 var connect = require('connect'),
  2     serveStatic = require('serve-static');
  3 
  4     var app = connect();
  5 
  6     app.use(serveStatic("./node_modules/angular"));
  7     app.listen(5000);
```

Below is my test html file.  It is located in the ~/node_modules/angular directory.

```
  1 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  2 <html>
  3 <head ng-app>
  4   <title>First Test</>
  5     <script src="angular.js"></script>
  6     <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  7     <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  8 </head>
  9 <body>
 10 <div class=“btn btn-default”>{{“AngularJS”}}</div>
 11 <div class=“btn btn-success”>Bootstrap</div>
 12 </body>
 13 </html>
```

My problem is the server starts with no issues.  The URL seems to be working.  However, nothing is displaying in the browser.  Where I go spying on the page.
I see nothing.

[image: Elements of the page]

I am getting back a http response of 200 when I look at the network tab:

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So what do you see in console when you run your server?

Comment: Do you have `“` instead of `"` in your code ? like - `“btn btn-default”>{{“AngularJS”}}</div>`

Comment: You should also put ng-app on the body not the head.

Comment: Nothing is showing up in the console.  I am using vi to edit the files.  I double checked the ["] to ensure all the ["] were the same.  I change things where they did not look alike.  In either case I am still seeing the same behavior.  Also moved the **ng-app** to the body of the html file.

Comment: You may be getting a cached version of the page - check the Network tab in the Dev Tools and make sure you're getting a 200 response and not a 304.

Comment: Yep, page is getting a 200 response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!  First of all thank you for your suggestions. Your comments and suggestions helped me work through my issue.

Here is what I changed:

```
  1 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  2 <html ng-app>
  3 <head lang="en">
  4   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  5   <title>First Test</title>
  6     <script src="angular.js" ></script>
  7     <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  8     <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  9 </head>
 10 <body>
 11 <div class="btn btn-default">{{"AngularJS"}}</div>
 12 <div class="btn btn-success">Bootstrap</div>
 13 </body>
 14 </html>
```

Now I have the correct response:

[image]