# Node.Js I can't run the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream, node.js-connect, node.js-domains

[This is what it supposed to do on Node.Js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxIJkNAXIX4)

I am stuck at 6:16 where it said "node server.js" where it supposed to open up 127.0.0.1:3000, but all I get is this error.

[image: descr]

on my browser it says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

There is nothing wrong with XAMMP and I don't really need port 80 to be open its for beta testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nodejs connect cannot find static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static)

Comment: FYI, most folks use Express these days rather than connect.  I believe they share some common lineage, but you may want to look into [Express](http://expressjs.com/) instead.

Comment: XAMPP is unrelated to what you are doing with node. Please accept the answer below (which is correct for the question).

Answer (score 1):

What the error in your console says is that the `static()` method is undefined and does not exist inside of the imported `connect` namespace i.e. the `connect package`.

[The api for Node's HTTP package](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_connection)

It seems that the `static()` method you use is a method for the `ExpressJS` framework.

[The api for the ExpressJS framework](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

So when you install `ExpressJS` and create the connection using that framework the method won't be undefined and everything will work as supposed.