# Warning: connect.static is not a function Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-connect

I am using YO lessapp project, "grunt-contrib-connect" helps me to start a node js server on 9000 port. Whenever I run grunt serve (start the server) the service is aborted due to the below warning.

```
Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Warning: connect.static is not a function Use --force to continue.
```

The exact error took place in the below function in Gruntfile.js

```
 livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function(connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
              connect.static(config.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
```

I have installed 
`npm install grunt-contrib-connect --save-dev`, 
`npm install serve-static --save-dev`

I came across few post, some suggest to turn off the firewall but no luck.

I know there is something to do with my machine or npm/node/connect version conflicts, because I tried to run the same app from other machine and it works fine.

System configuration :

- Windows 7 Professional
- Node -v4.1.2
- npm -v2.14.4
- connect@3.4.0

I have installed connect and serve-static based upon the post [nodejs connect cannot find static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static), but still the same

Any help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for your solution, It works after requiring serve-static inside grunt.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to install `connect` and `serve-static`:

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-connect serve-static
```

And then you have to import `serve-static` in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  ...
  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

  grunt.initConfig({
  ...
    connect: {
    ...
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function(connect) {
            return [
              serveStatic('.tmp'),
              connect().use('/bower_components', serveStatic('./bower_components')),
              serveStatic(config.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 28):

From version 0.11.x,  the new `grunt-contrib-connect` does not support `connect.static` and `connect.directory`.
 You should install `serve-static`(for serve static files) and `serve-index` (for Serves pages that contain directory listings for a given path).

like this:
`var serveStatic = require('serve-static');`
`var serveIndex = require('serve-index');`

Use `serveStatic` instead `connect.static`
and
`serveIndex` instead `connect.directory`

```
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
        options: {
            test: {
               directory: 'somePath',
               middleware: function(connect, options){
                    var _staticPath = path.resolve(options.directory);
                    return [serveStatic(_staticPath), serveIndex(_staticPath)]
               }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Following this answer, it's `require('serve-static')(.tmp)` that worked for me