# NodeJS package.json

Tags: json, node.js, installation

I'm setting NodeJS but when I run "connect", it says me that there is not "package.json".
I've installed NodeJS ->

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
$ npm install express
$ npm install connect
$ npm install serve-static
$ node server.js
```

But it doesnt work. In every "install" trying says that it doesn't find the package.json.

**Configuration:**
Windows: 10
NodeJS: 6.5.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a package.json (here using the default values by including `-y`) and then install the dependencies while saving them into the package.json using `-S`.

```
$ npm init -y
$ npm install -g express-generator
$ npm install express -S
$ npm install connect -S
$ npm install serve-static -S
$ node server.js
```

Note that you can leave out the installation of `express-generator` as it should already be installed globally.

[Documentation on npm init.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

Comment: Now it works, but on "node server.js" it says me that <<connection.static>> is not a function

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static you might find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ npm -g install express-generator
$ express (package_name)
$ npm install
```

These commands create a folder with the package_name in the current directory and install the required node modules with package.json

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file named `package.json` in your `main directory` like the following

```
{
  "name": "yourAppName",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
    "express": "~4.7.2",
     . . .
  }
}
```

That is just an example `package.json`. You can specify all the modules and version that you want to install trough `npm install`.

You get an error because your `package.json` does not exist. If you create it and re-run your command it will add your modules to it.

Hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For create a package.json, write the follow command into Dos: `npm init` for create step by step each parameter. Install the packages with parameter `--save` for annotate the package into package.json. for example : `npm install express --save`

Answer (score 0):

First create a `package.json` file. You can either create it using `npm init`  command or by creating a file manually as `package.json` in the particular path for ex if your node modules is on desktop then `/home/Desktop/node_modules/connect`. In the `package.json` file give the required details as in below format. For ex,

```
{
  "name": "connect",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies" : {
    "underscore": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

If you want to create `package.json` using `npm init` then at the command prompt it will ask for the details to be stored in `package.json` file by filling the respective values and pressing enter, `package.json` will be created. After that the you can install the module you want.

Answer (score 0):

run  **npm init** command on your command prompt to create a project,
it will automatically create a **package.json** file
once **package.json** file is created you can install other dependencies

ex:

npm install --save express

npm install --save restify