# Include CSS and JS in HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, httpserver, static-files

I saw that you can use `connect` to use serve static files in a Node.js HTTP server like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname + path));
http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

How would I implement this in my current handler?

```
var http = require("http");
var handler = function(request, response){
    // code
}
http.createServer(handler);
```

Is this even possible? If so, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Why don't you just specify the directory to serve static files in? i.e. app.use(express.static('public'))?

Comment: @vincentjp Because I'm not using Express.

Comment: See Using node.js as a simple web server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server

Comment: But it's so much easier.

Comment: @vincentjp But it's **_NOT_** what I'm using.

Comment: Well only the old versions of connect support that. You'd have to use serve-static if you want to use connect to serve static files.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use an older version of `connect` that might not function properly, you'd have to install `serve-static` to do what you're trying to do. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347442/5382465

```
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler')
var http = require('http')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

// Serve up public folder 
var serve = serveStatic('public', {'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm']})

// Create server 
var handler = http.createServer(function onRequest (req, res) {
  serve(req, res, finalhandler(req, res))
})

// Listen 
handler.listen(3000)
```