# Cannot GET /test.html when running Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am beginning to read Pro AngularJS. In the section to setup the development environment it has me create a angularjs directory and put a test.html file into it. Outside of that folder I installed 'connect' and 'serve-static' for Node.js. I also created a server.js file. The contents are seen below:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect().use(connect.static('/angularjs'));
app.listen(5000);
```

When visiting the following URL `http://localhost:5000/test.html` all I see is the text "Cannot GET /test.html".

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978734/node-connect-issue-object-function-createserver-has-no-method-static) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627441/cannot-get-with-connect-on-node-js) question here on SO. None of the solutions were helpful for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book didn't really do a good job of describing where to put server.js that I remember. So I had it one folder above the angularjs folder. Therefore, the '..' needed to be removed. I made the mistake of leaving in the '/' which caused my problems. Just as I figured ... a stupid small mistake (hardest to find).

Comment: Seriously it is a mistake in this book. For the past two hours I am also banging my head on this mistake. First there was an issue with static in connect module then this. Anyways thanks for the answer

Comment: Holy crap! You saved me so much pain in figuring out what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your `../angularjs` folder contains `test.html` file?

Then, you can try to resolve path

```
var connect = require('connect');
var path = require('path');
var app = connect().use(connect.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'angularjs')));
app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: '../angularjs' would be one directory up from server.js and inside the 'angularjs' directory. The test.html file does exist there

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
var app = connect().use(connect.static('/angularjs'));

use

var app = connect().use(connect.static('./angularjs'));

its worked for me

Comment: If you face the "nodejs connect cannot find static" error then refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346161/nodejs-connect-cannot-find-static

Answer (score -2):

Below worked out for me.

```
var connect=require('connect'),
    serveStatic=require('serve-static');

var path = require('path');
var server=connect();

server.use(serveStatic(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'angularjs')));

server.listen(5000);
```