# Undefined is not a function when using connect

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I'm trying to set up a simple HTTP server with connect on the node REPL. I tried the following,

```
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var app = connect()
  .use(connect.favicon())
  .use(connect.logger())
  .use(function(req,res) {
    res.end('Hello World\n');
});
```

But I get the following error,

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at repl:1:33
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)
```

I've already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830902/nodejs-webserver-undefined-is-not-a-function) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28844402/4316237) but it doesn't seem to help. I already made sure that `connect` was installed in my `node_modules` directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know why it's not working. Since I'm using version `3.3.5` of connect, they no longer provide certain middleware. They have been removed and you have to hunt for them manually. According to their GitHub [readme](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/Readme.md),

> Some middleware previously included with Connect are no longer supported by the Connect/Express team, are replaced by an alternative module, or should be superseded by a better module.