# insert php link in Gatsby / React

Tags: javascript, php, html, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to link my form page contactpage.php into my Gatsby application. In the navbar (in the Component folder) I have set this code

```
       <div>
        <a className="int_link_about" href='./contactpage.php'>Contacts</a>    
       </div>
```

However, when I click on the link it just downloads the php page, it does not display it. How to actually be redirected to it?

Also, right now in development I manually copied the contactpage.php in the 'public' folder but when I will switch to production, where should I put the page?

Comment: Is server set up to even run and serve php?

Comment: well I did not do anything with it so I guess not..Where can I look at documentation to check how to run it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a server related problem which can be checked by direct openning `/contactpage.php` 
Solve this and your React code should work. There is a complete thread solving this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627827/4281310

Comment: It says "cannot GET /contactpage.php"

Comment: So I guess you are using a **Node.js** as server right?

Comment: Take a look at this thread, there was a similar issue solved here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627827/4281310)